# Efficient method for finding index of first occurrence of a number in batched data other than for loop

Tags: numpy, for-loop, tensorflow, time-complexity, batch-processing

I am doing a task in which i have data in form of frames stored in batches. Dimension of a batch is like (batch_size,400), i want to find index of first occurrence of number 1 in each 400 length frame.

currently i m using for loop over batch size but since data is very larger it is very time consuming

Any  other Efficient method using some matrix operation in tensorflow or numpy would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TensorFlow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def index_of_first_tf(batch, value):
    eq = tf.equal(batch, value)
    has_value = tf.reduce_any(eq, axis=-1)
    _, idx = tf.math.top_k(tf.cast(eq, tf.int8))
    idx = tf.squeeze(idx, -1)
    return tf.where(has_value, idx, -tf.ones_like(idx))
```

In NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def index_of_first_np(batch, value):
    eq = np.equal(batch, value)
    has_value = np.any(eq, axis=-1)
    idx = np.argmax(eq, axis=-1)
    idx[~has_value] = -1
    return idx
```

Tests:

```
import tensorflow as tf

batch = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 1, 0],
         [0, 2, 3, 4]]
value = 1

print(index_of_first_np(batch, value))
# [ 1  0 -1]

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(index_of_first_tf(batch, value)))
    # [ 1  0 -1]
```